# Image opacity binding in windows phone apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I want to bind the opacity of an image to a slider control and I used this code:

```
<Image Source="sample.png" x:Name="sampleimg" Opacity="{Binding ElementName=opacityslider,Path=Value}"/>
<Slider x:Name="opacityslider" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="0.5" Width="200" />
```

This works fine but how to set the binding through c# code i.e in cs and not in xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way:

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = opacityslider;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
sampleimg.SetBinding(Image.OpacityProperty, b);
```